# I am unable to understand this how 5 <(5 or 10) is different from 5<(10 or 5)

Tags: python

I saw this problem yesterday
Print( 5 <( 5 or 10)) <- Output of this is False
Print( 5 <( 10 or 5)) <- Output of this is True
I wasn't able to understand it.
Like how the python is reading it why in one case it's False and True on the other one.

I got the idea that it's not distributive as it seems at first glance.
5 <( 5 or 10 ) != 5< 5 or 5 <10.

I wanna know how this function is read by python, and what is its meaning.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the correct site for programming questions (unless might be related to Unix-like environments), if it is not, you should use https://stackoverflow.com/ instead.

Comment: About your question, if you use `print( 10 or 5 )` the result will be `10` and if you use `print( 5 or 10 ) ` the result will be `5`, so I guess you are now able to understand why those results.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text; just post the text.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a line (or set of lines) of code and want to understand why they do what they do, a good tactic is to break the lines into component parts.  You're curious about why these lines return different results:

```
>>> print( 5 < ( 5 or 10 ) )
False
>>> print( 5 < ( 10 or 5 ) )
True
```

So let's pick it apart.  The only thing different about these lines of code is the parenthetical expressions, `( 5 or 10 )` and `( 10 or 5 )`, so let's look at how the Python handles them:

```
>>> ( 5 or 10 )
5
>>> ( 10 or 5 )
10
```

At this point, it should be clear why the output of the two `print()` statements differ:  They are effectively `print( 5 < 5 )` and `print( 5 < 10 )`- which are indeed `False` and `True` respectively.

But why does `( 5 or 10 )` evaluate to `5` and `( 10 or 5 )` to `10`?  For this, we consult the actual [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html), where we find in relevant part that for the Boolean `or` operator:

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is `True`, **its value is returned**; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

This makes sense if you are aware of how "truthiness" works in Python.  For numeric values, `0` and `0.0` are falsy values (i. e. values which in a Boolean operation evaluate to `False`) while any other value is truthy (i. e. evaluates to `True`).  Neither 5 nor 10 are falsy, so in each parenthetical case, the first value is returned, because that value would still itself evaluate to `True` in a Boolean test:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> if x:
...   print( f'{x} is truthy enough for me!' )
...
5 is truthy enough for me!
```

This allows, in potential use-cases, for `or` to work in a manner similar to an SQL `COALESCE()` (i. e. returning the first non-falsy value).  Should you have a set of variables each of which *could* be set to a truthy value in way that is valid for your program, and you want to prioritize which one you use, then `(x or y or z)` is a breviloquent way to do so.